# Log files for unit tests run through rake test along with backtrace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I am new Rails and trying to debug a project which has some failing unit tests. As I run 'rake test' it gives me lot of output on the console. I would like to know if there is some file which stores all this output which I can refer to. This will make it easier for me to search through the log. I come from the Eclipse world where Junit makes  it very easy to run/debug unit tests. I have skimmed through the guide for testing, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html but still couldnt find any information about logging in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
rake test testopts='-v' >mylog.txt
```

HTH.

Comment: Arent there any inbuilt options to log the output automatically to any files?